# Unable to share .fla file or its published html version on facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, flash, facebook-graph-api

I had created a simple flash animation using Adobe Flash Pro trial. When the file was ready on my system, I found I couldn't upload it to FB, as the format was not supported.

So I checked if this .fla could be converted to any of the standard video formats.

The only thing I could do with the fla file was to change its 'Publish Settings' to create a html and a js version. The html file opens well on my browser with the js.

But I'm not able to embed this html file onto FB either, as it's not standalone, but requires the js. Tried various file hosting servers too, including google drive...but they were not able to get my html going, it was static. So didn't use their share links either.

How to get this simple animation of mine successfully posted on FB?

Answer (score 1):

Export your FLA to QuickTime (MOV) or AVI.

**FILE  >  EXPORT  > EXPORT MOVIE**

NOTE: You can specify settings for the QuickTime movie to export. By default, QuickTime export creates a movie file using the same dimensions as the source Flash document.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn’t support flash `SWF` format (the `*.fla` is more like the raw file, not the rendered 'flash-movie' by the way). Note that it also doesn't support `gif`.

Facebook does however support most popular video file types, including FLV, 3GP, 3G2, ASF, DV, M2TS, M4V, MKV, MOD, MOV, MP4, MPEG, TOD, VOB, WMV, etc.

So you should google to find an (online) SWF to [one of the movie formats above] converter, and upload/link to the resulting movie.

**UPDATE**:
Why did I advise to use an external (optionally online) converter?

It is [well known](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4920423) that the stock AVI and MPEG4 compressors (bundled in Flash) *are pretty terrible*, except for Uncompressed (but then you get a huge file size).
<sup>This is once again a futile attempt (after decades of war) to hopefully make people install Quicktime.. which.. no sensible person does (unless they are really new computer users and nobody warned them) (just like RealPlayer.. anyone remember that and their their attempt to force something upon us and our computers that was hard if not impossible to remove again ??).</sup> 
So I'd highly advise to use a sensible (common and open) format, one that *everyone* can watch (don't push the internet back to that nineties war!).